# Render Wizard or View depends on my selection input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, ruby-on-rails-5, wizard

I'm new to rails

My Question is I want to create a form in which first i have option of choosing to give further input by manual or automatic way. When i choose manual and click next the wizard will take me to manual form and when i select automatic then it will take me to its respective step.

I'm using same model for both just views are different for manual and automatic. So Please help if anyone knows about it.

**Note:Currently I'm using a gem named wicked for wizards**

Comment: This is a very vague question and can be handled in many different ways. You can use javascript to submit to form to different paths. Or you can redirect on the backend to different forms. `params[:commit]` will tell you which button the user clicked.

Comment: That said - don't do this now. Form wizards are going to be way past your skill level at this point and it would probably be better if you focus on just learning the basics and conventions and circled back on this feature later when you know what you are doing.